# OWL and SPARQL mini application

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology, owl

The subject says it all. I need a mini project or application ideas that are related to OWL (some ontology represented in RDF written in OWL/XML) and queried by SPARQL. I need to do this project in my KBS (Knowledge-Based System) class within a week. So, the project needs to be really mini and applies one of the subjects I mentioned or subjects related to them. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the collection of books you have on your bookshelf. Find a suitable vocabulary to describe books, then model a useful fraction of your own collection. Write queries to summarise your collection (how many books you have, how many different authors, favourite topics, etc) or to produce a complete description of a book, given the title and author.

Next, use SPARQL to look one of your books' authors on dbpedia, to see if you can suggest other titles by that author.

Extension: what other information sources can you link to to add information about a book or an author?

Note, this is taking more of a linked-data approach. If your course emphasizes OWL reasoning, you'll have to adapt the above suggestions to add more reasoning-based queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/) framework. There are some samples packaged with it that might help you out.
Check these links as well:

- http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/Tutorial/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/j-sparql/